# How do I recover now zero-sized files?

Tags: data-recovery

I had cut a few image files from a memory card to my Ubuntu Desktop. 
I then used a software Namexif using Wine to modify the names of the files.
That was when my computer crashed for some time.

When I restarted the computer, the files that I had tried modifying were all corrupt and occupied zero bytes of memory.

How do I recover these files?

Comment: Using `gksudo nautilus`, navigate to the folder lost+found. If you have a separate partition for home, it will be in `/home/lost+found`, otherwise `/lost+found`. Unfortunately, it is unlikely to be there, but it is worth a try.

Answer (score 3):

Try using photorec, from the package `testdisk`. It's specifically designed to recover multimedia files from SD cards and pendrives. You'll lose the file names, but at least you'll recover your photos, probably.

[Here you can find a complete guide on using photorec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec_Step_By_Step).